# Slide left hidden div, slide right active div

Tags: jquery, hidden, absolute, parallax, sliding

I have series of divs, the first is active (showing a welcome screen with links).
The others are hidden divs absolute position left:-100% (these will also contain links).

I need to make it so that when a user clicks on a link, the current div slides out left (smoothly), and the new content slides in from the right (smoothly).

Parallax sliding isn't working for me because you can navigate to each slide from one an other, but i don't want the site to scroll through all the slides to reach the target container. I only want to have one scrolling sequence before reaching the requested content.

Most of what i have seen seems to be scrolling scripts that work with floated divs, so if you click link 3 you slide through 1,2,3. I need to miss out the middle stuff!
I hope this makes sense!?

Also if possible, i'd like the contents of the slides to be loaded dynamically?? But i'm totally lost with that one!!

**Here is the Code I've got so far...**

http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/5249/

This is almost what i need, but as you can see all the slides are being called in at the same time! ALL HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED!!!

```
html, body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px; 
overflow: hidden; 
}
.wrapper {
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;  
}
.slide{
position: absolute;
width: 200%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
left: 100%;
top:0px;
}
.navigation{
font-size:14px;
}
.navigation a{
display:block;
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
padding:5px;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
#slide1{
background-color:#000;
background-image:url(images/BG1.jpg);
background-position:center top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100%;
left: 0%;
}
.inner{
width:960px;
height:800px;
background-color:#fff;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
}
#slide2{
background-color:#090;

}
#slide3{
background-color:#F30;
}
.content{
width:30%;
height:80%;
float:right;
background-color:#fff;
margin:10%;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="slide" id="slide1">
<div class="inner">
   WELCOME CONTENT HERE
</div>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide2">
<div class="content">
      <div>SLIDE 2 DYNAMIC CONTENT LOADS HERE</div>
      <div class="navigation">
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 3</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 4</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 5</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 6</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 7</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 8</a>
      </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide3">
<div class="content">
      <div>SLIDE 3 DYNAMIC CONTENT LOADS HERE</div>
      <div class="navigation">
      <a class="button">BACK TO SLIDE 2</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 4</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 5</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 6</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 7</a>
      <a class="button">LINK TO SLIDE 8</a>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my solution and posted it in jsFiddle.
I haven't finished the solution but button 2 and three work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ns7sH/

```
$('.button2').click(function() {
    var thisElement = $('#slide2')[0]
    var previousElement = thisElement.previousElementSibling;

    $(previousElement).animate({
            left: '-100%',
        }, 1000 );

        $(thisElement).animate({
            left: '0%',
        }, 1000 );
```

});

It does not have the jquery ajax loading of content, I'll put that in when I have time later.

Comment: Hi I've tried your suggestion, but now nothing is happening. If you could implement in Jsfiddle that would be a great help! I'm a bit of a novice so except my apologies if this seems like a simple fix! Also, will your suggestion slide out the current showing div each time new slides are loaded? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Ok, think i fixed a small bug in the suggestion... $(this).animate({ left: '-100%' }, 1000 ); } }); return false; }); I've got slide 2 working however, it seems to slide over the current content rather than pushing it out to the left??

Comment: also if i'm on slide 3 how can i get slide 2 to slide back in from the left?

Comment: Oh right I understand what you want, I'll revise my solution and implementing it on jsFiddle when I get time (probably in the evening). Sorry I don't have the time right now.

Comment: No worries! Your help is very much appreciated! I'll keep checking back in for updates. Thanks in advance!

Comment: started working on a jsfiddle solution, not finished but should help you going until I have more time. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, i've almost got it!!!
http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/5275/

Now i just need help getting the back buttons to work and call the visited slides back in to view, anyone?????